# Minimum of N Chi-square random variables when N is large

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, random-variables, order-statistics

I have a problem in numerically evaluating the PDF of $Y=\min(X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_N)$ where $N=\binom{M}{K}$, the binomial coefficient and  $X_i$s are iid Chi-square random variables.

The CDF of $Y$ is $F_Y(y)=1-[1-F_X (y)]^N$, where $F_X (y)$ is the CDF of an $X_i$.

Then the PDF of $Y$ is $P_Y (y)=\frac{d}{dy}F_Y (y)=N [1-F_X (y)]^{N-1}P_X (y)$.

I have tired to plot $P_Y (y)$ for $M=100$ and $K=10$, I do not have any problem.
When $K$ increases keeping $M$ as constant, the PDF of $P_Y (y)$ exhibit a sharp transition from 0 to 1 in the lower tail and the area under the PDF does not  equal to 1 numerically. However, analytically the area can be shown to be equal to 1, that is, $\int_{0}^{\infty} P_Y (y) dy=1.$

My questions are

1. Why does the area does not equal to one when N increases? Is there a discontinuity happening as N increases?

We note that $0 \leq F_X (y) \leq 1$. Then, the term $[1-F_X (y)]^{N-1}$ in $P_Y (y)$ for large $N$ becomes a binary threshold function. Is there is a problem with the binary threshold function such as discontinuity?

Please help me, I do not know where I am making mistake.

Comment: Your problem with the computation are clearly numerical. As a first try, defgine the tail function $G_Y(y)= 1-F_Y(y)=(1-F_X(y))^N$.  Then you can first try to calculate the logarithm of the tail function!

Comment: Thank you. I will try an let you know.

Comment: As per your suggestion, $ln G_Y (y) = N*ln(1-F_X (y))$. Since $(1-F_X (y))$ lies between o and 1, $ln(1-F_X (y))$ is an negative number. But I still have to multiply by $N$, a very large number. any other idea. I still have the difficulty with the numerical computation.

Comment: Lets say $\ln(1-F_X(y))$ is $-10^{3}$ and $N=10^n$ is very large. The product becomes $-10^{3+n}$.  That exponent $3+n$ must become around $400$ (or a little smaller) before that is out of the dynamical range of dpuble precision numbers! That is a very large $N$!  How large is your $N$? If it is really that large, you need to use higher-precioson floats. Doubt that.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. My $N=\binom{M}{K}$, where $M=1000$ and $K=20$. The problem happens even for $M=100$ and $K=15$. Today I saw something about extreme order statistics. Do you know anything about that? does it help in my case?

Comment: Did you try my proposal?  Even M=1000 and K=20 when the binimial coefficient is approximately $e^41$ should be within reach for the logarithmic approach! Extreme value approach should be useful (maybe---it is most used for maxima). I can have a look at that, but later. Out of time now!  What is your application?

Comment: Here is R code for my suggestion. How does it work for you?                                                             # Code for question on math SE
#
logG_Y  <-  function(y, df, N, ncp=0)  {
    N * pchisq(y, df, ncp, lower.tail=FALSE, log.p=TRUE)
}

Comment: Extreme value approach for maximum can be converted for the minimum. I use MATLAB. In MATLAB, the value of $\binom{1000}{20} is 3.394828113024576e+41$.I will try with $R$ code then. My application is to find the extreme weather conditions in a local city.

Comment: Thank you for your R code. I have just downloaded it. I do not know how to use it..I will try.

Comment: For large $N$, the CDF $G_Y (y)= [1- F_X (y)]^N $ is a  "degenerate" distribution. Am I right? If yes, then it may be difficult to calculate it numerically.

Comment: Yes, it is "degenerate". You cannot expect to work with so small numbers with double-precision floats! thats why I do use the logarithm.  When you work with extremely small or big numbers numerically, logarithm is the way to go! For using the R code, it is important it is written exacltly as i did!  I will try do look into some aproximation approach (maybe extreme value theory), a bit later.

Comment: A similar question was asked here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/72114/order-statistics-e-g-minimum-of-infinite-collection-of-chi-square-variates

Comment: Thank you kjetil b halvorsen for your reply despite your busy schedule. I appreciate it. Since we are dealing with "degenerate" distribution, I guess "Extreme value theory" may provide some answer.

Comment: I would appreciate you kjetil b halvorsen if would look in to the extreme value theory. Thanks..

Comment: You could have a look at this paper and see if it helps!      http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10687-010-0125-3

Comment: Thanks a lot kjetil b halvorsen. I just scan through the paper. I think it will solve my problem. I really appreciate your time and help. I will let you know what I learned.